# how to query graph.facebook with postman?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, postman

I'm using postman to query from Facebook Graph API. I'm trying next line:
`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?access_token=my_access_token=<here is my user token>`
and i get:

`{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid OAuth access token.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 190,
    "fbtrace_id": "ASBwgp9xF/R"
  }
}`
I can't figure out alone the right syntax
the access token works at [facebook graph api explorer.](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/Explorer)

Answer (score 5):

You don´t even need postman for this, just hit the URL in your browser.

This is the correct one:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?access_token=<here is my user token>
```

Comment: works, thanks! so for what more complicated cases postman was created for?

Comment: for post requests, for example